# Hive queries in Spark cluster

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I need to understand how the hive query will get executed in Spark cluster. It will operate as a Mapreduce job running in memory or it will use the spark architecture for running the hive queries. Pls clarify.

Answer (score 1):

If you run hive queries in hive or beeline it will use Map-reduce, but if you run hive queries in spark REPL or program the queries will simply get converted into dataframes and created the logical and physical plan same as data frame and executes. Hence will use all the power of spark.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have a Hadoop cluster with YARN and Spark configured;

Hive execution engine is controlled by `hive.execution.engine` property. According to the [docs](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties) it can be `mr` (default), `tez` or `spark`.